# Terraform Kubernetes provider not available to get data from ressource provisioned

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, provider

I'm trying to use the Kubernetes Terraform provider. Everytime I try to create a resource with helm provider and get data from this with Kubernetes provider, I'm not able to make it working within the same script as the kubernetes data isn't created (and no dependency detected between provider) at the launch time.

For example in the same script I'd like to do the following :

```
#define de required provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    kubernetes = {
      source = "hashicorp/kubernetes"
      version = "2.7.1"
    }
  }
}
    
provider "kubernetes" {
   host = var.host
   token = var.token
   insecure = true
}

#define the helm provider
provider "helm" {
  kubernetes {
    host = var.host
    token = var.token
    insecure = true
  }
}


#deploy grafana chart, as example app
resource "helm_release" "grafana" {
  name       = "grafana"
  namespace  = "grafana"

  repository = "https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts"
  chart      = "grafana"

  values = [
    templatefile("${path.module}/grafana-values.tftpl", {
        grafana_username = var.grafana_username,
        grafana_password = var.grafana_password}
    )
  ]
}

data "kubernetes_service" "grafana" {
  metadata {
    name = "grafana"
    namespace = "grafana"
  }
}

output "service_ip"{
    value = data.kubernetes_service.grafana.status[0].load_balancer[0].ingress[0].ip
    depends_on = [data.kubernetes_service.grafana]
}
```

It looks it's not possible to create Kubernetes ressource from a different provider than kubernetes? Or am I doing something wrong?

If I run this a second time one the helm chart is already deployed, then the output will be correct.

Comment: How about `data.kubernetes_service.grafana.status.0.load_balancer.0.ingress.0.ip` and dropping the `depends_on` from the output?

Comment: What terraform and provider version you are using? If I understand you want to use Helm chart within terraform script? What errors do you have when you will use `terraform plan`?

Comment: @MarkoE : I tried as well. It doesn't work

Comment: @PjoterS : I got this error :
`
│ Error: Attempt to index null value
│ 
│   on main.tf line 41, in output "service_ip":
│   41:     value = data.kubernetes_service.grafana.status[0].load_balancer[0].ingress[0].ip
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.kubernetes_service.grafana.status is null
│ 
│ This value is null, so it does not have any indices.
`
The problem is that at the time I do the plan or apply, the service doesn't exist yet, as it will be created by the helm chart.

Comment: @PjoterS I'm running Kubernetes provider 2.7.1 and terraform v.1.1.6

Comment: @Fab There's also a `status` reported as an attribute by the `helm_release` resource: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/helm/latest/docs/resources/release#status. I'd check what that will output first and not use the `data` source.

Comment: @MarkoE Unfortunately the helm_release status doesn't provide the information deployed such as Service External IP address

Comment: @Fab curious to hear if you solved this and if so, what was the error?